# computational strategy for solving convex-concave minmax problem

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume f(x,y) is convex in $x$ and concave in $y$.
Then \begin{equation}\min_x \max_y f(x,y)\end{equation} is globally solvable, because f is convex in x (max of convex is convex.)
**But can we find a globally optimal $x$ with coordinate descent? (aka alternating: i.e Fix x, find optimal y. Fix $y$ find optimal $x$ till convergence.) Why or why not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an example: $f(x,y) = x y$.  The optimal solution is $(x,y)=(0,0)$.  If you allow all real values of $x$ and $y$, then for fixed $x \ne 0$ there is no optimal $y$.
But let's say you restrict to a bounded domain,  $-1 \le x \le 1$, $-1 \le y \le 1$.
The optimal $y$ for $x=1$ is $1$.  The optimal $x$ for $y=1$ is $-1$.  The optimal $y$ for $x=-1$ is $-1$.  The optimal $x$ for $y=-1$ is $1$.  And so your procedure cycles.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The update cycles, but when averaged over time the average does converge to the optimum. That can be seen in the example and holds quite generally.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I think it would be more helpful if you could provide more details regarding your answer to better answer the OP. Just some friendly advice. Regards